# Importing Leaflet for Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, typescript-typings

I'm pretty new to Angular 2, and looking for steps involved in setting up Leafletjs with Angular 2. Looking to avoid including JS and CSS into my index.html. It should not be imported globally, as I'm building a widget.

Any help at all would be very appreciated.

Comment: There's the [angular2-leaflet-starter](https://github.com/haoliangyu/angular2-leaflet-starter), but they don't use angular-cli. I used [mapbox-gl](https://www.mapbox.com/), it was easy enough once I figured out how to get it in a component, unfortunately I had to import it directly into my component like `const mapboxgl = require('../../../node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js');`, and `const Map = mapboxgl.Map`.

Comment: I guess you want this as a global package.
Begin with installing the package using: npm install leaflet --save when you are in your root folder of the project. When you have installed the package you should be able to enter the path's for the style and script files in angular-cli.json under the sections:  "styles": [] and "scripts": [].

Comment: Thanks. It's not global though. I'm making a widget, so I'll need to import it into a specific module/component. I haven't really imported an external library before. Do I need to use require()?

Comment: @BBaysinger updated my response, i have never worked with leaflet but i think that should work.

Comment: Have you tried `npm install @types/leaflet --save`?  I'm still new to this, but referencing [the DefinitelyTyped repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) like that seems to set the library up correctly.  I'm [having a harder time with plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024405/how-do-i-structure-a-typings-definition-file-for-a-plugin-of-another-library).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Begin with installing the package using 
`npm install leaflet --save`
 when you are in your root folder of the project.

**I you want Leaflet as a global package:**

When package is installed you should be able to enter the path's for the style and script files found under node_modules/ in *angular-cli.json* under the sections: `"styles": []` and `"scripts": []`

You can read more about this at the [angular-cli project page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation).

**If you want to import the package into a existing module**

On the top of your module write:

```
import leaflet from 'leaflet';
```

Comment: had to `import L` instead of `import leaflet`